# request body is empty in django

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I am using create react app for front end.My problem is every POST request contains nothing from django side. Here is the view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print(request.POST) // prints <QueryDict: {}>
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return JsonResponse({'token': str(token[0])}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Username/Password is not valid'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I already added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` in package.json.

Here is the react part:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "/api/auth/",
            data : {
                "username": this.state.username,
                "password": this.state.password
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.error(error.response.data["error"]);
        })
    }
```

I also checked front end network data, there were username and password in request body.

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'notes', views.NotesViewset)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/auth/', views.login),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', views.BunnyAppView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: try with `request.data` not `request.POST`

Comment: AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
@JahongirRahmonov

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: django 1.11.6  and drf 3.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get data in `request.data`, `request.POST` is for form-encoded data.

But if you want data in request.POST QueryDict you need to encode data.

> axios default content-type is `application/json`.

axios supports `URLSearchParams` which can be used to send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` from the browser:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('username', this.state.username);
params.append('password', this.state.password);

axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/api/auth/",
      data : params
})
```

Or you can encode the data using a library like `qs`:

```
var qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 });
```

Comment: still same problem.

Comment: i guess there is something wrong with url of your request. can you add urlpattern of login view to question

Comment: i have updated my answer. let me know for any issue, change `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: now I got a weird output of ```request.POST```,

```<QueryDict: {'{"username":"prism","password":"1234"}': ['']}> ```

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem in axios and django. To prevent the empty request body, self.request.data should be used.
Here is the entire working solution :

axios:

```
axios.defaults.headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Token " + this.props.token
}
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/categoryCreate/', {
    name: name,
})
.then(res => {

})
```

views.py

```
class CategoryCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategoryCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.data)
        name = self.request.data["name"]
        print(name)
        serializer.save(name=name, user=self.request.user)
```

serializers.py

```
class CategoryCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Flokkur
        fields = ('name', )
```

urls.py:

```
path('categoryCreate/', CategoryCreateAPIView.as_view()),
```